# Binding SpeechStateEnumeration to TextBlock

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

How do we bind an enumeration to a `TextBlock`?

In code-behind, I have:

```
public enum SpeechStateEnumeration
{
    Listening,
    Recording,
    Dictating,
    Working,
    Sleeping,
    Unresponsive
}

public static SpeechStateEnumeration SpeechState;

button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SpeechState = SpeechStateEnumeration.Sleeping;
}
```

And my XAML is:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Status" Text="{Binding SpeechState}" />
```

But it doesn't work. If I set `SpeechState` to "Listening" or "Sleeping", for example, how can I convey that to the user through the `TextBlock`?

Comment: Have you implmented the INotifyProperty?

Comment: @7200rpm: `INotifyPropertyChanged` to be exact ;). But that should be the solution. But it can't be used with static properties. You could make the view model e.g. a singleton.

Comment: Nah. I haven't done that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it isn't picking up the binding is because you cannot bind to `fields`. You need to have at least have an `auto-property` to actually bind.

The following works fine for me:

*Code Behind:*

```
public SpeechStateEnumeration SpeechState { get; set; }

public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SpeechState = SpeechStateEnumeration.Listening;
    DataContext = this;
}
```

*XAML:*

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SpeechState}" />
```